# How to implement a dependency injection outside startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Im trying to implement a dependency inection outside the startup.cs (in a controller to be more precise). Byt it doesn't work.
I can't get the IServiceColection anywhere outside the startup.cs

```
public class ServiceEidaServiceInjection : IServiceEidaServiceInjection
    {
        List<EidaServiceDTO> eidaServices;
        IServiceCollection Services;
        public ServiceEidaServiceInjection(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Services = services;
        }
        public void InjectEidaServices()
        {
            eidaServices = new EidaServiceBLL().GetAll();
            foreach (EidaServiceDTO eidaService in eidaServices)
            {
                Services.RegisterType(typeof(ServiceEidaServiceInjection).Assembly, eidaService.InterfaceName, eidaService.ClassName);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to call InjectEidaServices() in the LoginController but the injection of IServiceCollection in this cass doesn't work.

PS : InjectEidaService() gets to call a extesion method of IServiceCollection to register Services.

Comment: Why do you want to register a new component based an endpoint call? Or are you looking for self-registration?

Comment: Only in the login controlller that i have the DbContext.
Before login the user would find him self in Admin database, after the login the user will find himself in EidaDatabase. All the services i want to be registered in InjectEidaServices() need EidaDatabase context

Comment: The suggested way to register a `DbContext` is to register it as a `Transient`. (Because it is not thread-safe you should not register it as `Singleton`). So, because you are registering as `Transient` that means a new instance will be created on-demand. That's why you can register it at startup time and should not have to register through your LoginController. Does it make sense?